# Pytesseract OCR doesn't recognize the digits

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to read these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried several options but I can't seem to read them correctly as 15/0, 30/0, 40/0.

```
    frame = frame[900:1000, 450:500]
    scale_percent = 200  # percent of original size
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow("cropped", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow("cropped", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
        r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    )
    results = pytesseract.image_to_data(
        frame,
        output_type=Output.DICT,
        config="--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789",
    )
    # results = replace_chars(results)
    print(("-").join(results["text"]), "\n")
```

Comment: It does the best it can.  Notice that scaling up does not increase the accuracy -- all you do is make the edges fuzzy.

Comment: I doubt I am using the best way as it doesn' recognize anything. It can't miss the "0" at least surely if it s correctly used, can it?

Comment: `--psm 10` says to treat the image as a single character.  That's DEFINITELY not what you want.  You probably want 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks I have tried with 1 and it detects nothing. 2 gives an error.

Comment: psm 6 works for me.

Comment: oh yes 6 is much better. Thanks. Still some mistakes but much better. Would it be more reliable to develop a ML model to recognize those numbers?

Comment: For Some reason it struggles to read "0". It can read 15, 30, 40 but not 0. it doesn't read it as the letter "O" either (I had some doubt and thought it might be the issue). Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving is using [inRange thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

The result will be:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

If you set [page-segmentation-mode](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) 6

```
15
0

30
0

40
0
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
from numpy import array

image_list = ["LZxCs.png", "W06I0.png", "vvzE5.png"]

for image in image_list:
    bgr_image = cv2.imread(image)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, array([0, 0, 0]), array([165, 10, 255]))
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
    thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(dilate, mask)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='--psm 6')
    print(text)
```

The second way is applying [global-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/db/d8e/tutorial_threshold.html)

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

If you set [page-segmentation-mode](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) 6

```
15
0

30
0

40
0
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

image_list = ["LZxCs.png", "W06I0.png", "vvzE5.png"]

for image in image_list:
    bgr_image = cv2.imread(image)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='--psm 6')
    print(text)
    cv2.imwrite(f"/Users/ahx/Desktop/{image}", thresh)
    cv2.imshow('', thresh)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For more, you can check the [documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still have a few mistakes where instead of 0 the model sees:
- ie)
- fe)
- te)
But I ll hardcode them.
Great anyway!

Comment: Did you have the latest tesseract module installed?

Comment: Yes. I m reading a video frame by frame where I analyse a specific region to get the images I mentioned. But I gues son some frames it s not as clear as what I have uploaded. Anyway thanks again.